# What is WM_KEYDOWN in c++

Tags: c++, windows, keydown

I'm new to c++ and wondering what "WM_KEYDOWN" is? 
And how to use it.

Thank you.

Comment: This is far too broad. Google around, do some research, get a good book on Windows GUI programming in C++ and come back with any specific problems you have.

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2441480/884410](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2441480/884410)

Comment: This site worked for me to start learning the Win32 API: [winprog](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial)

Comment: If you're new to C++ you should maybe try something easier than Win32 api ...

Comment: I just saw that, you'll need a decent understanding of the language before you can begin to cope with it.

Comment: Oh, and by the by, there's a tag for the API should you have future questions about it: [winapi]

Comment: Things like this can easily be solved with a quick trip to google. You can search WM_KEYDOWN and MSDN would most likely be the first link. MSDN is a great resource to use for all things win32.

Answer (score 3):

`WM_KEYDOWN` is defined in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown):

```
#define WM_KEYDOWN  0x0100
```

While I don't have a better explanation than Microsoft's, I'll post what the doc says:

> Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a nonsystem key is pressed. A nonsystem key is a key that is pressed when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is not pressed.

Simply put, it is a value returned by Windows in a program when a key on the keyboard is pressed (and when <kbd>Alt</kbd> isn't). The opposite is `WM_KEYUP`, which will be emitted when you release the key.

Answer (score 1):

A message flag produced by your window when your key is pressed.
You can use it in the message handler function like

`LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);`

Then register it to your WNDCLASS

```
WNDCLASS ws;
ws.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg153546(v=VS.85).aspx for more information about how to dual with WM_KEYDOWN in WndProc.