# How to capture special key events?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

On my laptop I have several special keys, not found on a standard keyboard, like changing performance profiles. The vendor supplied a software that handles this key.
Is there a way to catch this key event from a custom program? As far as I know Windows internally works with messages. How could I listen to all keyboard related messages and log the id of the key so I could know later which key id should handle?

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2441457/2513200) can provide a starting point?

Comment: That's a good start, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Register Hotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be what you are looking for,  you can handle normal keyboard interaction as normal and use Register Hotkey to handle the hotkeys.

You may also want to take a look at http://www.autohotkey.com/ which provides a pre-made version of what you are looking for.  (may not suit your needs though, so not sure about this)

Another approach would be to use [wh_keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_keyboardhook) hook (with an example located [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699/Hooking-the-Keyboard.htm) on how to utilise this as a DLL).  And an overview of Windows Hooks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).